# how to search an epub document for a specific word (in windows)?

Tags: epub

I have a document in epub format open in Firefox, but can't find any option to search for a specific word. It only has option to search within the page currently viewed, not the whole document. Is there such possibility, or alternative ways to search the epub file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try a different ereader such as Coolreader. Additionally, epub documents are zip files usually. If all else fails, you might be able to unzip it and then do a textual search on the individual html source files.

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same problem. I found the answer here and I downloaded "Coolreader". In fact, it didn't work. Maybe there are bags in this program. Anyway, I found other free program ([Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/)) which works very well now for searching in the entire book.

I am posting this answer for others who come this post by googling and may spend time by downloading the program which is mentioned here in the previous answer. ([this is the the article](https://icecreamapps.com/blog/best-epub-readers-for-windows/) that I found this program in. There are other programs there but some of them didn't work properly and some of them I didn't try since I found already what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

[Sumatra PDF reader](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader) is a small free PDF, eBook (ePub, mobi), XPS, DjVu, CHM, Comic Book (CBZ and CBR) reader for Windows. It can be installed or run as portable.

With the default configuration, if you open a epub file, you don't have  the option to search in the file.
[image]

**However**, if you go to Settings -> Advanced Settings, you go to a "SumatraPDF-settings.txt" file.

In that file, it you change from the original (emphasis mine):

EbookUI [
...
UseFixedPageUI = **false**
]

to

EbookUI [
...
UseFixedPageUI = **true**
]

and save it, when you next open an epub file, you will have a toolbar with the Find option.

[image]

Comment: Excellent tip.  Thank you!